# User Logging automation via Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I Have this task for my company where i have to do a monthly User access review via cloudwatch.

This is a manual process where i have to go to cloudwatch > cloudwatch_logs > log_groups > /var/log/example_access > example-instance and then document the logs for a list of users from random generated date. The example instance is a certificate manager box which is linked to our entire production fleet nodes. I also have to document what command that user used on a specific nodes.

Wondering is there any way i can automate this process and dump it into word docs? it's getting painful as the list of user/employees are increasing. Thanks

Comment: You can subscribe your log group to lambda or elasticsearch for automated processing of new entries  You can also dump them to S3 and process them from there. Not sure if this is what you are after?

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is, I don't reckon you want Word docs though, I'd launch an elasticsearch instance on AWS and then give users who want data Kibana access.

Also circulating word docs in an org is bad juju, depending on your windows/office version it carries risks.

Add this lambda function and then go into cloudwatch and add it as subscription filter to the right log groups.

Note you may get missing log entries if they're not logged in JSON format or have funky formatting, if you're using a standard log format it should work.

```
/* eslint-disable */
// Eslint disabled as this is adapted AWS code.

const zlib = require('zlib')
const elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch')

/**
 * This is an example function to stream CloudWatch logs to ElasticSearch.
 * @param event
 * @param context
 * @param callback
 * @param utils
 */
export default (event, context, callback) => {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true

    const payload = new Buffer(event.awslogs.data, 'base64')

    const esClient = new elasticsearch.Client({
        httpAuth: process.env.esAuth, // your params here
        host: process.env.esEndpoint, // your params here.
    })

    zlib.gunzip(payload, (err, result) => {

        if (err) {
            return callback(null, err)
        }

        const logObject = JSON.parse(result.toString('utf8'))

        const elasticsearchBulkData = transform(logObject)

        const params = { body: [] }
        params.body.push(elasticsearchBulkData)

        esClient.bulk(params, (err, resp) => {

            if (err) {
        callback(null, 'success')
        return
    }

        })

        callback(null, 'success')
    })
}

function transform(payload) {
    if (payload.messageType === 'CONTROL_MESSAGE') {
        return null
    }

    let bulkRequestBody = ''

    payload.logEvents.forEach((logEvent) => {
        const timestamp = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp)

        // index name format: cwl-YYYY.MM.DD
        const indexName = [
            `cwl-${process.env.NODE_ENV}-${timestamp.getUTCFullYear()}`,              // year
            (`0${timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1}`).slice(-2),  // month
            (`0${timestamp.getUTCDate()}`).slice(-2),          // day
        ].join('.')

        const source = buildSource(logEvent.message, logEvent.extractedFields)
        source['@id'] = logEvent.id
        source['@timestamp'] = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp).toISOString()
        source['@message'] = logEvent.message
        source['@owner'] = payload.owner
        source['@log_group'] = payload.logGroup
        source['@log_stream'] = payload.logStream

        const action = { index: {} }
        action.index._index = indexName
        action.index._type = 'lambdaLogs'
        action.index._id = logEvent.id

        bulkRequestBody += `${[
            JSON.stringify(action),
            JSON.stringify(source),
        ].join('\n')}\n`
    })
    return bulkRequestBody
}

function buildSource(message, extractedFields) {
    if (extractedFields) {
        const source = {}

        for (const key in extractedFields) {
            if (extractedFields.hasOwnProperty(key) && extractedFields[key]) {
                const value = extractedFields[key]

                if (isNumeric(value)) {
                    source[key] = 1 * value
                    continue
                }

                const jsonSubString = extractJson(value)
                if (jsonSubString !== null) {
                    source[`$${key}`] = JSON.parse(jsonSubString)
                }

                source[key] = value
            }
        }
        return source
    }

    const jsonSubString = extractJson(message)
    if (jsonSubString !== null) {
        return JSON.parse(jsonSubString)
    }

    return {}
}

function extractJson(message) {
    const jsonStart = message.indexOf('{')
    if (jsonStart < 0) return null
    const jsonSubString = message.substring(jsonStart)
    return isValidJson(jsonSubString) ? jsonSubString : null
}

function isValidJson(message) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(message)
    } catch (e) { return false }
    return true
}

function isNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)
}
```

Now you should have your logs going into elastic, go into Kibana and you can search by date and even write endpoints to allow people to query their own data!

Easy way is just give stakeholders Kibana access and let them check it out.

Might not be exactly what ya wanted by I reckon it'll work better.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. we already have elasticsearch/kibana integration for logging. The only reason i needed it for .docx format cause we need to provide this to the auditors for SOC compliance. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ahhh OK, silly me, sorry right so....what do you need help with automation or word docs or both?